# 3d matrix rotation - object rotates strangely

Tags: ios, matrix, 3d, rotation

I'm experimenting with rotation matrices to turn a wireframe cube about its X axis.

However, I can't figure out how to set the origin of the rotation to anything other than 0,0,0..

And the strangest thing - as I increase the angle (in degrees), the object rotates faster and faster.. 
So the cube performs a full rotation (around an origin of 0,0,0) when the rotation angle is at roughly 8 degrees.. And then at 11 degrees, etc..

I've tried three tutorial methods, copying the code and plugging it into my vertex system. And each matrix code leads to the same behaviour.

Here's the method I'm using - the matrix is defined in Matrix_Handler with the relevant trigonometry..

```
-(void) GLmatrixRotation:(HeyaldaGLDrawNode*) GLpolygon angle:(float)angle {

  matrix X_Matrix, Y_Matrix, Z_Matrix, Final_Matrix;

  int vertexCount = GLpolygon.dynamicVertCount;

  x_angle = angle;
  y_angle = 0;
  z_angle = 0;

  float xOrigin = 150;
  float yOrigin = 150;
  float zOrigin = 0;

  Matrix_Handler(X_Matrix, Y_Matrix, Z_Matrix, deg_to_rad(x_angle), deg_to_rad(y_angle), deg_to_rad(z_angle));
  Concatenate_Matrices(X_Matrix, Y_Matrix, Z_Matrix, Final_Matrix);

  for (int i=0; i<vertexCount; i++) {
    HeyaldaPoint v = GLpolygon.dynamicVerts[i];
    HeyaldaPoint vt;

    HeyaldaPoint newPoint;

    // translate for new origin
    v.x = v.x + xOrigin;
    v.y = v.y + yOrigin;
    v.z = v.z + zOrigin;

    newPoint.x = (Final_Matrix[0][0] * v.x) + (Final_Matrix[0][1] * v.y) + (Final_Matrix[0][2] * v.z);
    newPoint.y = (Final_Matrix[1][0] * v.x) + (Final_Matrix[1][1] * v.y) + (Final_Matrix[1][2] * v.z);
    newPoint.z = (Final_Matrix[2][0] * v.x) + (Final_Matrix[2][1] * v.y) + (Final_Matrix[2][2] * v.z);

    // translate back to old origin
    newPoint.x = newPoint.x - xOrigin;
    newPoint.y = newPoint.y - yOrigin;
    newPoint.z = newPoint.z - zOrigin;

    GLpolygon.dynamicVerts[i] = newPoint;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Aah silly me!

I misunderstood the matrix transformation - I was assuming that passing a rotation angle would rotate the shape TO that angle..

Instead, it rotates the shape BY that angle.. So if I rotate the shape with angle = 10, it turns the shape 10 degrees.. It doesn't turn it TO 10 degrees.

And to set the origin point from which we rotate, I need to reverse the translation math (set it to minus) -

```
// translate for new origin
v.x = v.x - xOrigin;
v.y = v.y - yOrigin;
v.z = v.z - zOrigin;

// translate back to old origin
newPoint.x = newPoint.x + xOrigin;
newPoint.y = newPoint.y + yOrigin;
newPoint.z = newPoint.z + zOrigin;
```

And also - the origin needs to be set in all three coordinates -

```
float xOrigin = 150;
float yOrigin = 150;
float zOrigin = 150;
```